# google analytics says tracking not installed

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

Hi i have added the script given by google into the head section and able to see it in the view page source but still google says that tracker not installed.Website is jhcsnagpur.com

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-46285312-1', 'jhcsnagpur.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting?

Comment: Use `<script type="text/javascript">`, though I don't think that's the problem. Have you any JS errors in your console?